# Dynamic list of button with events from xml

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, linq, silverlight-4.0

I'm working on silverlight rss reader as schoolproject and I have one problem.
I want to define list of feed sources in xml and load this xml to list of button, each button for one feed.
xml looks like

```
<FeedList>  
  <Feed ButtonContent="HDRip's on RlsLog.net" Url="http://www.rlslog.net/category/movies/hdrip/feed/" />
</FeedList>
```

I'm loading this xml using linq and creating button

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(string.Format("feeds.xml"));

if (xdoc != null)
{                 
    var feedlist =
        (from l in xdoc.Descendants("Feed")
            select new MyButtons
            {
                 Content = l.Attribute("ButtonContent").Value,
                 FeedUrl = l.Attribute("Url").Value
            }
        ).ToList();

    foreach (MyButtons feedbutton in feedlist)
    {
        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.Content = feedbutton.Content;
        b1.Click += (s, e) => { feedViewer.LoadFeed(feedbutton.FeedUrl); };
        ButtonPanel.Children.Add(b1);
    }
}
```

button content is loading fine but that feed url is used the last one in xml for all buttons. could you please advice me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I understand whats wrong.. I'm creating list of buttons and all are named b1 with same b1.click event.. but how to do list of buttons corretly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `feedbutton` is being captured as an iteration variable, thus causing the behavior you're describing when you assign the event handler with the lambda expression.

Try this instead:

```
MyButtons tempButton = feedbutton;
b1.Click += (s, e) => { feedViewer.LoadFeed(tempButton.FeedUrl); };
```

Eric Lippert has blogged about this topic:

- [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)
- [Closing over the loop variable, part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx)

Comment: Actually I understand whats wrong.. I'm creating list of buttons and all are named b1 with same b1.click event.. but how to do list of buttons corretly?

Comment: @Gabbo are you sure we're on the same page? Please try my suggestion first and let me know if the issue hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Ahmad, sorry i made a mistake on first try of your solution.. now it's working fine. Thank you for your advice, it really helped me so much.

Comment: @Gabbo no problem, glad that helped :) I highly recommend reading those links I shared. Just be mindful of closures and captured variables when using lambda expressions.